# Laravel RESTful controller to include subdirectory for 'show' function

Tags: php, laravel

I am building my Laravel app through the use of RESTful controllers.

Currently, an 'agent' can login, to view all of their 'notifications'.

The structure is:

> /agents

When they chose a notification to view, instead of:

> /agents/$id

I want it to be:

> /agents/notifications/$id

Solely because it follows logically. If it was '/agents/$id' I would expect to see the agent's profile, for example.

Is there a way of including a subdirectory into the 'show' function? Or do I need to create a notification controller that somehow sites within the agent directory.

My route is:

> Route::controller('agents', 'AgentsController');

With the show function:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $alerts = Alert::where('id', $id)->first();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.notification.show', array('alerts' => $alerts));
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers then your controller's method should be named getShow().
Apart from that you can achieve what you want by defining another route like this:

```
Route::get('agents/notifications/{id}', 'AgentsController@getShow');
```

Comment: Yeah, simply: you don't need a new controller, but you need a new route. I'm not a huge fan of RESTful controllers myself, it's too limited in most use cases.